# Unable to install Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am unable to install firebase tool.

```
> C:\Users\Mohit Saini>npm i -g firebase-tools
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ePY2w==","shasum":"89'
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly run `npm cache clean --force` to clear previous caches

after that run `npm cache verify` which will bring 0 bytes indicating all cache was cleared.

lastly run `npm install -g firebase-tools`

note: running the `clean --force` command will deletes all data from your cache folder.

Answer (score 0):

When I [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+WARN+deprecated+request%402.88.2+firebase), this Github issue shows up: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2215, which seems to indicate the problem can be fixed by running:

```
npm cache verify
```

If you get problems installing the CLI, and are not familiar enough with the environment to fix them, I'd recommend [installing the standalone binary](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli) version of the Firebase CLI instead.